# React Axios POST Access to XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

When I want to send a post request, everything works fine and returns an echo of the php file, but when I want to pass a "user" variable it returns:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http: // localhost / en / login' from origin 'http: // localhost: 3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

I tried adding the header at the beginning of the php file:

header ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

This has solved the problem of not being able to send any request, but when I try to send a variable the error mentioned above appears.

REACT:

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const {user, pass} = this.state;
  const data = {user:user,password:pass};
  axios.post('http://localhost/es/login', data)
      .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });

};
```

PHP:

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
echo "hola";/*
```

Comment: try removing the host and just have the path `/es/login`

Comment: The "hosts" are not the same, it have different port, react port is 3000 and I'm trying to do the post request to the api